# How to make a div's background image shrink when the window is resized?

Tags: html, css

I have a div in my webpage with an image as its background.
When I make the browser window smaller, the right-hand part of the image gets cut off.

The code below is in my .css file:

```
.captions {
    max-width: 870px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background-image: url('../images/0.png');
    height:20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

and this code is in my HTML page:

```
<div class="captions"></div>
```

Could someone please advise me how I get the width of the background image to shrink when the page is resized, so that the entire length of the image is always shown?

I am reasonable new to css and would really appreciate help regarding the code.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting the width to a calculate expression? ie `width: calc(100%)` - this way it's always 100% of the current width of the containing window.

Answer (score 0):

Use the background-size CSS3 property. It lets you specify what size you want for that background image. In this case we set it to 100% on both width and height (though you might want to change that to width only). And also set the .captions container to 100% width so it adjusts accordingly.

Working example:

```
.captions {
    max-width: 870px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background-image: url('../images/0.png');
    height:20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using padding percentage to set the height, because `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` percentage is linked to container width. And `padding-top` is calculated by dividing the image height by width.

```
.captions {
    background-image: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 29.8%;
    height: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

***[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTns7/)***